# Compiling jar from terminal, exception: "error: package au.com.bytecode.opencsv does not exist'"

Tags: java, jar, terminal

So, my package structure is that I have a src folder with my code and inside that I have an exec folder with a class and three methods, my main class and two jars.

My exec class looks like this:

```
package com.xxx.exec;

import au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVReader;


import java.io.*;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

/**
 * Created by xxx on 24/07/16.
 */

public class ApiAccess {

    public void getConsoleInput() throws Exception {
        Console console = System.console();
        if (console == null) {
            throw new Exception("Unable to fetch console");
        }
        System.out.println("Please enter the location:");
        getAPIData(console.readLine());
    }

    private void writeCsv(InputStream input) {
        try {
            CSVReader locationData = new CSVReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
            locationData.close();
            System.out.println(input);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Something went wrong while creating the csv:" + e);
        }

    }

    private void getAPIData(String location) throws IOException {
        String url = "http://exec.goeuro.com/exec/v2/position/suggest/en/";
        String charset = StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name();

        String query = String.format(url + "%s", URLEncoder.encode(location, charset));
        URLConnection connection = new URL(query).openConnection();
        connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", charset);

//        String line;
//        StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
//        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
//        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
//            text.append(line).append(" ");
//        }
//
//        writeCsv(text.toString());
        writeCsv(connection.getInputStream());

    }
}
```

My terminal command looks like this:

```
javac -cp ".:lib/*:opencsv-2.41.jar" -d src $(find ./src/* | grep .java)
```

And I get this Error:

```
./src/com/goeuro/exec/ApiAccess.java:3: error: package au.com.bytecode.opencsv does not exist
import au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVReader;
                              ^
./src/com/goeuro/exec/ApiAccess.java:29: error: cannot find symbol
            CSVReader locationData = new CSVReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
            ^
  symbol:   class CSVReader
  location: class ApiAccess
./src/com/goeuro/exec/ApiAccess.java:29: error: cannot find symbol
            CSVReader locationData = new CSVReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
                                         ^
  symbol:   class CSVReader
  location: class ApiAccess
3 errors
```

Thank you in advance for any answers!

Current dir structure (I put a backslash in front of directories):

```
/src >
       -/com.xxx >
                 -Main.java,
                  -/exec >
                       -ApiAccess,
                       -opencsv-2.41.jar >
                                        -/au.com.bytecode.opencsv,
                       -commons-lang3-3.0.1.jar
```

[image]

Comment: Please show us the locations of the JAR files relative to the current directory.

Comment: @StephenC Hey, I added the structure :)

Comment: I am waiting for you to fix that so that it is 1) readable and 2) accurate

Comment: @StephenC I fixed the readability. Sorry about that. It's accurate otherwise. I had the dependencies in the external lib folder before installed with maven but extracted them and put them in the exec folder to try if it would make my live easier if I just had the files at the same location, but I also changed the path in my intellij project structure after I did that.

Comment: @StephenC I added a screenshot, did not know I was allowed to do that :) The CSVMaker file is empty and unimportant, it's a leftover from something I tried previously.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not convinced I understand your directory structure.  Your ASCII and image seems to be saying that you have hidden JAR files 3 or 4 levels deep in the >>source<< directory, which is (IMO) a bit crazy.

Instead, I recommend the following structure:

```
src/
    com/
        xxx/
            Main.java            // class name "com.xxx.Main"
            exec/
                 APIAccess.java  // class name "com.xxx.exec.APIAccess"
lib/
    opencsv-2.41.jar
    commons-lang3-3.0.1.jar
classes/
    com/
        xxx/
            Main.class
            exec/
                 APIAccess.class
```

And compile the classes like this:

```
javac -cp "classes:lib/*" -d classes $(find src/* | grep .java)
```

And run like the application like this:

```
java -cp "classes:lib/*" com.xxx.Main
```

Salient points about the above:

- The "src" tree structure must mirror the package structure with the Java files appearing in the place that their package naming dictates.
- The "classes" tree is separate so that:

  - it is easy to create a JAR without source code
  - it is easy to "clean" the ".class" files
  - you don't have to worry about checking ".class" files into version control by accident.
- The "classes" tree will naturally mirror the package structure.  The compiler will take care of that.
- The "lib" directory is separate from the "src" tree.

  - It is easy to find.
  - points as above about version control.  Note that it is bad practice to check external dependencies into version control.

(If you are not using version control, you should learn how to do that.  It will save you a lot of hurt.  Also, look at switching to a Java build tool.  Look at tools like Maven and Gradle that can handle external dependencies well.)